# Adding microphone input to MediaMuxer Android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-audiorecord, mediamuxer, android-mediaprojection

Hey I'm trying to develop screencast app which would record the contents of the screen as well as microphone input. I was able to implement the video recording but I can't find anything about adding microphone input to mediaMuxer.
I know I could use mediarecorder class but how then could i add the mediarecorder to muxer?
I've found this bits of code so far.

```
 MediaFormat audioFormat = new MediaFormat(...);
 int audioTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);
```

While I could add an audioFormat to the muxer I'm not sure how could I add the microphone input to the muxer. Could someone point me in the right direction or provide some sort of sample code?

Comment: One possible approach: just use MediaRecorder. As of API 21 you can get an input Surface from a MediaRecorder and send the video to that -- you're not limited to Camera input anymore.

Comment: I could do just that but I want to stick with mediaMuxer as it's a bit more flexible than mediaRecorder.

Answer (score 0):

Media recorder is much better alternate than media muxer for taking input from MIC while recording the screen

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/capture.mp4");
```

[here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/) is the full code.

Comment: I wouldn't say "much better". `MediaRecorder` gives you less control compared to `MediaMuxer`, although it is simpler to use, and is enough for most use cases